# Defines a $ P $ function with values in $ R $ (justifying)

Tags: functions

Let $ P = \left\{1,2,3,4\right\}$ and $ R = \left\{x \in \mathbb{Z} | -4 \leq x \leq 4 \right\}$. In each case, check if the given law defines a $ P $ function with values in $ R $, justifying:

a) $y \leq x$
b) $y= -x$
c) $y= \sqrt{x}$

**Attemp:** If I'm understanding this problem correctly, then for a) it will be that all 4 values in P work, as 4 is greater than or equal to all of 1,2,3,4, and for b) it will again be that all four work, because for 1 it's -1, for 2 it's -2, for 3 it's -3, and finally for 4 it's -4. For c), only 1 and 2 work because for 3 and 4 their squares are greater than 4

Am I right?

Comment: Hello! I think this problem wants you to check in each case if the given *relation* on $P$ and $R$ satisfies the special constraints on a relation to be called a *function from $P$ to $R$*. (In short, we want it to be the case that for each $x \in P$, there is exactly one $y \in R$ satisfying the relation). I'm not sure what you mean when you say some elements "work" - a relation is either a function, or it isn't! Hint: at least one of these is a function, and at least one is not.